# I have made an accordian menu but the links which have no submenus do not work

Tags: javascript, menu, hyperlink

I have made an accordian menu and mostly everything is working grand. the submenu links are working and the sliding is grand. The thing is, the links which do not have submenus are not working. I have a js file which has the following snippet of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){ 
e.preventDefault();     
}
if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) { 
    // hide any open menus and remove all other classes                 
    // open our new menu and add the open class       
    $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);       
    $(this).addClass("open");     
    }       
    else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {      
     $(this).removeClass("open");       
    $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);     
    }  
     }); 
    });
```

As you can see at the top it states that if the parent of a has another child ul then prevent that link a from opening, which works fine for the links which have submenus. However you would think this would still enable the links with no 'ul' sibling to work, but they don't work. For example the 'call us' does not go to the specified page "open.htm". I appreciate any help. Thank you. My html:

```
<div id="content">

    <div>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="block1"><img class="navicon" src="images/maps_30_white1.png" height="30" width="30" alt="Find Us" /><span class="button_desc">Find Us</span></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="open.htm#">Call Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="open.htm#"><span class="block1"><img class="navicon" src="images/clock_white1.png" height="30" width="30" alt="Opening Hours" /><span class="button_desc">Opening Hours</span></span></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><span class="block1"><img class="navicon" src="images/arrow_white.png" height="30" width="30" alt="Shop" /><span class="button_desc">Departments</span></span></a>  
                    <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=design+cartoons+animation">Cartoons</a></h4></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=design+comic+strips+inspiration">Comic Strips</a></h4></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=how+to+clip+video+footage">Video Clips</a></h4></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=design+create+animated+gifs">Web GIFs</a></h4></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="block1"><img class="navicon" src="images/arrow_white.png" height="30" width="30" alt="Shop" /><span class="button_desc">Brands</span></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=photoshop+tutorials+graphics+design">Adobe Photoshop</a></h4></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=digital+branding+graphics+logos">Branding & Logos</a></h4></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="block1"><img class="navicon" src="images/arrow_white.png" height="30" width="30" alt="Shop" /><span class="button_desc">Gift Ideas</span></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h4><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=photoshop+tutorials+graphics+design">Adobe Photoshop</a></h4></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=digital+branding+graphics+logos">Branding & Logos</a></h4></li>
                        <li><h4><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=graphics+design+marketing">Digital Marketing</a></h4></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. There is a `}` after the prevent default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if the text represents a sub menu (example: Brand), why is it in an anchor tag? If you want to show an image and some text, you can do that using css or img tag.
Remove  for UL headers.

Second, you need to remove e.preventDefault(). This is the reason why your single links are not going to the next page.

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="www.google.com">Call Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><span class="block open">List Header</span>

                <ul>
                    <li>List item 1</li>
                    <li>List item ...</li>
                    <li>List item n</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Your fixed JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav > li > .block").on("click", function (e) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
            // hide any open menus and remove all other classes                 
            // open our new menu and add the open class       
            $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
            $(this).addClass("open");
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $(this).removeClass("open");
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
        }
    });
});
```

Live demo/fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/tRDzr/1/
```

Comment: I was using anchor tags so that I could style them in css when active or on hover but I don't really need to do that. I tried this code. This works perfect. I have styled the 'block' class in the same way I have the main anchor tags of the nav styled so it looks the same. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you.. Good luck! If the question has been answered, please mark mine as the answer.. vote up will be appreciated.

Comment: I have marked yours as the answer. I would like to vote up but I need a minimum of 15 reputation. Next time. :) Thank you.